# How do you find the parametric and cartesian equation and include three points a, b and c?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> Given three points 
>   $a = (1,4,0), b=(2,1,5), c=(3,5,2)$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$, find each of the following
>
> $iii)$ A parametric equation of the plane containing $a$, $b$ and $c$

My solution:
$$(x,y,z) = (1,4,0) + t_{1}(2,1,5) + t_{2}(3,5,2)$$
$$x=1+2t_{1}+3t_{2}, \space\space y=4+t_{1}+5t_{2}, \space\space y=0+5t_{1}+2t_{2}$$

> $iv)$ A Cartesian equation of the plain containing $a$, $b$ and $c$

My solution:
I need a vector and a plane. Use $\vec{ab} = (1,-3,5)$
$$v = A(x-x_{0})+B(y-y_{1})+C(z-z_{0})$$ with perpendicular line

> $v)$ A vector perpendicular to the plane containing $a$, $b$ and $c$

Comment: the equation of your plane is wrong

Answer (score 1):

for iii) it must be
$\vec{x}=(1,4,0)+t_1((2,1,5)-(1,4,0))+t_2((3,5,2)-(1,4,0))$
$\vec{x}=(1,4,0)+t_1(1,-3,5)+t_2(2,1,2)$

Comment: Why was (1,4,0) subtracted from $t_1 and t_2$?

Comment: not from $t_1$ and $t_2$ for ntwo given points $a=(1,4,0$ and $b=(2,1,5)$ is a vector $(2,1,5)-(1,4,0)=(1,-3,5)$

Comment: Wait so you subtract everything by $a$ point in order to create  vectors $\vec{ab} \space and \space \vec{ac}$ and then have them multiplied bt $t_1$ and $t_2$